# What is the best design practice for excluding a certain subset of data in the database model

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, database-design

Scenario.

I have a library shelf, library, user, application tables in the database. One library shelf can have many library files. I want to associate the files to users under each application. I can have users under one application access library files using a  UserXLibraryShelf table. Lets say rather than saying what shelves are available for the users, i want to say which shelves will not be available. Most times users will have access to all the shelves except say for applications 3 and 5. I can do this probably by having a UserXNotAvailableShelf. but then this works like a look up table and i have to say bring all the shelves that do not exist in the NotAvailable table for this user.

What is the best practice for handling exception scenarios (exclude rather than include) in the database design.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with the look-up table approach...

Comment: is it fast enough when there is a lot of records? I will have to say get the files where shelves are not in the look up table.

Comment: How many is "a lot"? How much data do you expect in this system? Would you be able to set up a few simple tests with generated data to see how your queries perform with large amounts of data and properly tuned indicies?

Comment: And will you want to fetch the files for a specific user only or sometimes for all of them?

Comment: it is always for a specific user. The data could grow indefinitely. the qureies that have "id not in" types are not usually very fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a perfectly acceptable design choice to have (base) tables for both 'available' and 'unavailable', ensuring that every shelf/user correspondence goes into exactly one of those tables. However, there may be practical problems of such a design in an update-intensive environment. p.s. have you considered creating groups of users then corresponding shelvers with these groups?

Comment: yes, it will be per group of users. kind of like, for this group, these shelves are available or not available based on what i decide. Its either one or the other because the master list of shelves is the same. so I either need to store unavailable or available. Unavailable is shorter storage of data but available is faster and is straightforward. Somebody has to remember to check for unavailable all the time. it is an exception to normal flow.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done using Roles in MS-SQL. For example, you create a VIEW or PROCEDURE that excludes certain shelf values and assign it to a role and a VIEW/PROC that includes all shelves and assign it to another role. Users are then assigned to the appropriate roles.